# DE/ Double Optin

Tags: marketing-cloud

We collect data from different sources i.E. Event registrations, whitepaper downloads, product configuration and save each source in a own Data Extension (user contact data + source specific data). We also ask in each source if the user want's to receive Newsletter and save it as a boolean field in each DE.

1. Does is make sense to separate each data source as own DE, each entry has contact data as firstname and lastname saved, which is a lot of duplicate data

   2. How to transfer contact data (firstname, lastname) from multiple DE's to Contact Attributes?
   3. Is it a good way to manage the DOI through a Journey?

Comment: What is does  DOI stand for??

Comment: @Data_Kid DOI stands for Double Opt-In

Comment: Thank God I asked. I assumed it was "Declaration of Interest"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Ideally you would have the preferences together with your "MasterSubscriberDE" - a placeholder for your 'Single Customer View". I would advise using these data sources as staging tables and creating a unified view via a MasterSubscriberDE. I have seen instances where preferences are located on another table, usually because the MasterSubscriberDE has too many rows/columns, and might lead to queries to populate it timing out as it reaches millions.
2. To do this, you would have to map them onto your data model in contact builder. Having them in one place in your MasterSubscriberDE saves to the hassle of mapping multiple table to a contact key..

Comment: Thanks! Where can I find this MasterSubdcriberDE?

Comment: It's not out of the box. You create as a normal Data Extension . Would advise to have this in place and build segments off it.\

Comment: How do you mean build segments off it?

Comment: Will invite you to chat as might be a long discussion

Comment: Can't figure out how to invite to chat. Basically you have data from all your data feeds. Create a MasterSubscriberDE with the Key attributes you would use for personalization (Name, Email, Preferences (Newletteer groups etc).  Use a SQL query to bring in all the data from the different sources into this. You dont want to bring in everything as the table will be big and result in performance issues. Now that you have all this data in one place, it is easier to  create different segments (simpler queries), and the data model becomes more streamlined.

Comment: I have added you